# Delete special rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, rows

I want to delete the rows which have special words. for example the three columns data:

> 10   s    123
>
> 24   c    235
>
> 33   s    345
>
> 46   s    346
>
> 59   s    546
>
> 62   c    277

Now I want to delete the rows that have the word "s" and I want just the remaining rows:

> 24   c    235
>
> 62   c    277

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on autofilter, and filter for rows that contain "s".  Then delete the rows that are showing.  Alternately, you can filter for rows that do not contain "s" and copy/paste them into another spreadsheet, depending on what your actual criteria is.

Comment: If I want to put some word before each number of a column,how can I do that. I mean : for example I put the word "k" before 24 and 62 to get k24 and k62.?

Comment: @asd: That should be asked as a separate question.